# android use AutoCompleteTextView in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, autocompletetextview

I am using `AutoCompleteTextView` in each `recyclerview` row, then i got the problem when dropdown show, it overlay `autocompletetextview`, so can see what I text in this.

[image]

Here is my xml for recyclerview adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:drawme="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.rafakob.drawme.DrawMeTextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        drawme:dm_backColor="@color/background_light"
        drawme:dm_radiusTopLeft="10dp"
        drawme:dm_radiusTopRight="10dp">

        <requestFocus />
    </com.rafakob.drawme.DrawMeTextView>

    <com.rafakob.drawme.DrawMeLinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        drawme:dm_backColor="@color/grayColor70"
        drawme:dm_radiusBottomLeft="10dp"
        drawme:dm_radiusBottomRight="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp">


                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/machine"
                        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="46dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </com.rafakob.drawme.DrawMeLinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In code i'm using normal implement with using arrayAdapter, then setadapter for that autocompletetextview
In manifest i set adjustPan|adjustResize but still not working. Does anyone have solution for this?

UPDATE
 I just tested with only autocompletetextview as a child of RecyclerView row. The result image below: 
[image]

Comment: share your xml layout with quetion

Comment: updated xml layout. Thanks

Comment: for test case remove `<requestFocus />` from your `<com.rafakob.drawme.DrawMeTextView`

Comment: still not working.... :(

Comment: i updated case only autucompletetextview as child of RecyclerView row

Comment: try with this **adjustNothing** for test case

Comment: still not working sir....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161154/discussion-between-prem-and-kemdo).

Answer (score 1):

After reading [AutoCompleteTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) document from Android, i found the solution is just use `android:dropDownVerticalOffset`
it's solve my problem ^.,.^